# Create jasper user in an organizaition

Tags: java, amqp, jasperserver

I am trying to achieve a goal where my web application and jasper are working like microservices. I use rabbitmq to pass user details from my web app to jasper. I have successfully developed a consumer for jasper and now i am facing a trouble in creating user in an organisation. i followed the jasper's API and wrote my code.([Users and Roles API](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v630/users-and-roles-api))

I am getting this error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This implementation does not support tenants
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.getPersistentTenant(UserAuthorityServiceImpl.java:2029)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.getRepoUser(UserAuthorityServiceImpl.java:175)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.getRepoUser(UserAuthorityServiceImpl.java:232)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.doPutUser(UserAuthorityServiceImpl.java:327)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.UserAuthorityServiceImpl.putUser(UserAuthorityServiceImpl.java:316)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

I simply have below classes.

**UserConsumer.java**

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UsersConsumer implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    JasperUserManager jasperUserManager;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("==========MESSAGE========>>>>>>>>>> : "+message.toString());
            jasperUserManager.saveUser();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**JasperUserManager.java**

```
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.domain.ExecutionContext;
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.domain.User;
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.ObjectPermissionService;
import com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.UserAuthorityService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class JasperUserManagerImpl implements JasperUserManager {

    @Autowired
    private UserAuthorityService userAuthorityService;

    @Override
    public void saveUser() {
        User user = userAuthorityService.newUser(null);
        user.setUsername("thusira");
        user.setTenantId("ACT");
        user.setPassword("123");
        user.setFullName("Thusira Dissanayake");
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setExternallyDefined(false);
        userAuthorityService.putUser(null, user);
        System.out.println("================SSSSSSSSSUUCESSS================================");
    }

}
```

Please help me what would be the issue in my implementation.

Thank you in advance

BR,
Thusira

After using MTUserAuthorityService got this exception,

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.putUser(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.putUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.cinglevue.veip.report.users.JasperUserManagerImpl.saveUser(JasperUserManagerImpl.java:33)
    at com.cinglevue.veip.report.users.UsersConsumer.onMessage(UsersConsumer.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `UserAuthorityService` has two implementations. One of these is a simple `UserAuthorityServiceImpl` which doesn't know anything about tenants unlike the `MTUserAuthorityServiceImpl` which can save users with tenants.

- So firstly you should check your XML configuration. `js.spring.properties` should contains this line:
  `bean.userAuthorityService=mtUserAuthorityService`
- As the second approach, you can inject directly the `MTUserAuthorityServiceImpl` bean.
  For example in this way:

```java
@Component
public class JasperUserManagerImpl implements JasperUserManager {

    @Resource(name="")
    private UserAuthorityService userAuthorityService;

    @Override
    public void saveUser() {
        User user = userAuthorityService.newUser(null);
        user.setUsername("thusira");
        user.setTenantId("ACT");
        user.setPassword("123");
        user.setFullName("Thusira Dissanayake");
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setExternallyDefined(false);
        userAuthorityService.putUser(null, user);  
    }
}
```

- And in the last case, you probably don't have Jasperserver MultipleTenancy license (for example if you work with community edition) and as result, you can't work with tenants at all.

Comment: Hi thanks, i actually used MTUserAuthorityServiceImpl and it gives me this exception "org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
"

Comment: Can you give me the full stack trace?

Comment: I have added to the question. Please find it above.

Comment: I think you are not authorized when you want to save a user. Try to call `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` for check if you logged in. If you are not authorized  you can login by the `userAuthorityService.makeUserLoggedIn(superuser)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I didn't know that we have method to use , i re-invent the wheel. It worked.